# Initialization of 'UnsafePointer<UInt8>' results in a dangling pointer

Tags: swift, xcode, swift5

Trying to clean up some warnings in my SWIFT 5/XCODE project and I'm stuck on this one:

```
 let sendBytes:[UInt8] = [0x0, 0x0, 0x5, 0x0]
 let msgData = Data(bytes: UnsafePointer<UInt8>(sendBytes), count: sendBytes.count)
 socket.write(msgData, withTimeout: -1.0, tag: 0)
 socket.readData(withTimeout: -1.0, tag: 0)
```

For the "UnsafePointer" I'm getting the following warning and two suggestions:

Initialization of 'UnsafePointer' results in a dangling pointer

1. Implicit argument conversion from '[UInt8]' to 'UnsafePointer' produces a pointer valid only for the duration of the call to 'init(_:)'
2. Use the 'withUnsafeBufferPointer' method on Array in order to explicitly convert argument to buffer pointer valid for a defined scope

This is my solution, better?

**Version 1:**

```
let sendBytes:[UInt8] = [0x0, 0x0, 0x5, 0x0]
let uint8Pointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: sendBytes.count)
uint8Pointer.initialize(from: sendBytes, count: sendBytes.count)
let msgData = Data(bytes: uint8Pointer, count: sendBytes.count)
socket.write(msgData, withTimeout: -1.0, tag: 0)
socket.readData(withTimeout: -1.0, tag: 0)
```

**Version 2:**

```
let sendBytes:[UInt8] = [0x0, 0x0, 0x5, 0x0]                     
let uint8Pointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: sendBytes.count)
uint8Pointer.initialize(from: sendBytes, count: sendBytes.count)
let msgData = Data(bytes: uint8Pointer, count: sendBytes.count)
socket.write(msgData, withTimeout: -1.0, tag: 0)
socket.readData(withTimeout: -1.0, tag: 0)
uint8Pointer.deallocate()
```

Comment: Are you asking why you're getting this warning or how to fix it? For the former (in case it's not clear), `sendBytes` will be deallocated when this function (presumably `init`) returns. At that point, the `UnsafePointer` to it is no longer valid (it points to deallocated memory), so if `msgData` tries to use it later it will result in "bad" behavior.

Comment: Hi, Alex -- I added my solution above -- is that a better way to handle?

Comment: That indeed addresses the scope issue, but now you will have a memory leak unless you manually call `deallocate` on the ptr (after it's done being used). From docs: "You are responsible for handling the life cycle of any memory you work with through unsafe pointers to avoid leaks or undefined behavior."

Comment: Got it!  I added Version 2 above -- after I send the bytes I deallocate the pointer.

Comment: It's impossible to say for sure without knowing exactly what `socket.write` does (e.g. if it stores the ptr in a global variable and tries to access it later, this will break); but assuming it just writes the data then that looks good. If that's how you use `msgData`, your original code is probably also fine (since `msgData` is only used before it goes out of scope)

Comment: yes, it was working flawlessly before -- just didn't like the warnings and now the code should be a little better anyways.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since Swift 3 it's possible to simply initialize a `Data` instance with an `UInt8` array.

```
let sendBytes:[UInt8] = [0x0, 0x0, 0x5, 0x0]
let msgData = Data(sendBytes)
```

Comment: Bam!  That works -- this was very old code and simply removing the "UnsafePointer<UInt8>" removed the warning in XCODE.

Comment: I love answers like this